# Develop a third-party bundle (or library) in local

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to develop a public and third-party bundle for Symfony. To test the bundle during the development, I need a functional Symfony installation.
So I need to mimic a Composer installation of my bundle in the Symfony test application.

The problem is, what is the best way to achieve that ? It would be wonderful if composer could just let us define a local repository, and without the need to commit on the package side then do the `composer update` on the Symfony app side **each time you want to test the bundle**.
The solution I'm explaining here is explained here : http://tech.vg.no/2014/11/25/using-local-packages-as-composer-dependencies/

This is the best solution I have found for now and I don't see a lot of literature about that. So this is a call to "Symfony 3rd-party bundles developers": how do you develop and test your bundles during the development?

Comment: wow, a downvote and a close vote, what is so wrong in my question ? If the solution is that simple, I need a captain obvious or a doc link.

Comment: The composer approach is probably your best bet.  You can also edit app/autoload.php and just add a path to your library.  That removes composer from the process.  Git also supports nested repositories so you could actually develop under the test app's vendor branch but I find it to be a bit confusing.

Comment: "You can also edit app/autoload.php and just add a path to your library"
(vendor/autoload.php you mean ?)
Would that be different from adding a PSR rule into the test app's composer.json or even create a symlink to my bundle folder ? Because the problem of this solution is that it doesn't take in account the bundle's composer.json with its dependencies etc, unlike a bundle that you install via Composer.

Comment: I don't know who DOWNVOTED but he should definitely reconsider. Although this seems to be a "trivial" question, it actually is not that well documented!

Comment: This isn't going to help you, but worth noting that npm has the `link` command to help with this. I've not used it so not sure if it is something composer should copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify my comment about app/autoload.php, Symfony 2 gives you a little hook to allow customizing the autoload process:

```
// app/autoload.php
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Cerad',   __DIR__  . '/../../cerad2/src');
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));
return $loader;
```

So in the above case the cerad2 library located somewhere else on the file system will be used.

Is this better than simply adjusting the test app's composer file?  Probably not though it does come in handy.  Use whichever approach works best for you.

Comment: Yes, patching autoload, adding psr rule, symlinking, etc, are acceptable solutions for the bundle development. However this will require a second test app to regularly test the bundle's composer.json (to test a regular installation of the bundle). I was searching for a solution that could mix the both (mimic an installation while still directly accessing to the "live files"), but probably this is inexistent. Thank you! If some people have a better solution, tell us!